# How can I change the output format for GDAL in QGIS 3.28.13

Tags: qgis, gdal, geotiff-tiff, output

Many of the raster operations do not work because the output of the GDAL is set to GMT by default rather than GTiff. How can that be changed easily without having to resort to writing Python code? AT the moment this version of QGIS is severely limited due to this default setting. Why can't the default changed in some higher order switch?

Comment: which version? what operating system? which processes? TBH I've never seen it offer anything but GeoTiff.

Answer (score 3):

Change the Options -> Processing -> General -> Default output raster layer extension to tif.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. That solved the problem.